# C# properties settings works from the second time on

Tags: winforms

Here's the problem: I've published an app made with Windows Forms with ClickOnce. Therefore, I can't show Terms of Service before install. The client decided to show some Terms of Service page after the install, and if the user agreed with the terms by pressing the button, show the main app. Problem is, after install the app shows the ToS, the user accepts, and after the first restart the user is shown the ToS again! If he accepts, the next time the user opens the app (either after a restart or after the app is closed and opened again) this problem will no longer appear, i.e. if the user agreed to the ToS the main app will show up, without asking the ToS.

The code defining the tos in settings:

```
[global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("False")]
public bool tos {
    get {
        return ((bool)(this["tos"]));
    }
    set {
        this["tos"] = value;
    }
}
```

The code that checks for ToS when the app starts:

```
bool tosB = Properties.Settings.Default.tos;
if (!tosB)
{
    this.tab_control.SelectTab(this.TOS_PAGE);
    this.richTextBox1.Rtf = 
        global::MyAppName.Properties.Resources.terms_and_conditions;
}
else
{
    check_connectivity();
}
```

The code that runs when the user cliks the **I agree** button:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.tos = true;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = 
        Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(
            "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
    key.SetValue("My App Name", Application.ExecutablePath.ToString());
    check_connectivity();
}
```